# Apache with Subversion crashes on MacOSX Mavericks

Tags: svn, apache-http-server, osx-mavericks

After installing MacOSX Mavericks the other night I noticed my little SVN server set-up had stopped working. I recompiled all of the current Subversion sources as per the instructions. Now it works unto the point of authentication and then it fails.

When I run svn-serve I get a perfect SVN server.

Apache SVN config:

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module libexec/apache2/mod_dav_svn.so 
LoadModule authz_svn_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_svn.so 

<Location /svn> 
  DAV svn 
  SVNParentPath /Volumes/Users/svn 

  SSLRequireSSL 

  AuthType Basic 
  AuthName "Subversion repository" 
  AuthUserFile /private/etc/apache2/subversion.auth 

  Require valid-user 
</Location>
```

After searching the web I found instruction to use lldb and I got:

```
(lldb) thread backtrace all
* thread #1: tid = 0x43651, 0x00007fff8a8c2812 libsystem_c.dylib`strlen + 18, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
  frame #0: 0x00007fff8a8c2812 libsystem_c.dylib`strlen + 18
  frame #1: 0x00000001061710e0 mod_hfs_apple.so`___lldb_unnamed_function3$$mod_hfs_apple.so + 52
  frame #2: 0x0000000105e5448d httpd`ap_run_fixups + 109
  frame #3: 0x0000000105e55395 httpd`ap_process_request_internal + 1621
  frame #4: 0x0000000105e5f752 httpd`ap_process_request + 98
  frame #5: 0x0000000105e5b823 httpd`ap_process_http_connection + 147
  frame #6: 0x0000000105e3e97d httpd`ap_run_process_connection + 109
  frame #7: 0x0000000105e3ef45 httpd`ap_process_connection + 117
  frame #8: 0x0000000105e69893 httpd`child_main + 1587
  frame #9: 0x0000000105e682ee httpd`make_child + 414
  frame #10: 0x0000000105e683a0 httpd`startup_children + 128
  frame #11: 0x0000000105e673d4 httpd`ap_mpm_run + 708
  frame #12: 0x0000000105e32a8e httpd`main + 3278
  frame #13: 0x00007fff90cb35fd libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

And now I'm clueless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known issue with the current versions.  You can use the patch here:
https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-users/201310.mbox/%3C5271AB05.5050802%40reser.org%3E

Alternatively you can unload mod_hfs_apple if you're not using httpd for anything other than SVN since there's no need for it in that case.